# split a file based on a pattern

Tags: shell, unix, split, ksh

I have a file which would have below pattern

```
HDR1|20160101|1234|
N1|ABC|
XXX|21431415|3522352352|ITEM|
FORE|20140508|20140214|
SD|0|0039 - data|data|data|data|
SD|0|0211 - data|data|data|data|
SD|0|0039 - data|data|data|data|
SD|0|0211 - data|data|data|data|
FORE|20140508|20140214|
SD|0|0039 - data|data|data|data|
SD|0|0039 - data|data|data|data|
SD|0|0211 - data|data|data|data|
```

I would like to split the file based on size but also need to take care of the below.

The first 3 lines is the header, which I need to include in every split file that I create.
The line starting with FORE has relation its below lines starting with SD so I have to keep them all together.

The output should look like below.

Split File 1:

```
HDR1|20160101|1234|
N1|ABC|
XXX|21431415|3522352352|ITEM|
FORE|20140508|20140214|
SD|0|0039 - data|data|data|data|
SD|0|0211 - data|data|data|data|
SD|0|0039 - data|data|data|data|
SD|0|0211 - data|data|data|data|
```

Split File 2:

```
HDR1|20160101|1234|
N1|ABC|
XXX|21431415|3522352352|ITEM|
FORE|20140508|20140214|
SD|0|0039 - data|data|data|data|
SD|0|0039 - data|data|data|data|
SD|0|0211 - data|data|data|data|
```

I have built a pseudo code which looks like below.There can be multiple sets of such FORE and SD which I've to keep together as a set, so I've put a loop

```
create $file
create $line_num=5
create $file_size
create $top_size=20mb
read the first 4 lines of the original file and copy it in a temphdr file
    Loop until last $line_num is encountered
        read the header details and Append the header from the temphdr to the $file
        for each $record starting the head -$line_num (5,6,7...etc) that contains FORE| in the first part
            if the $file size is < $top_size
                append the $record in the $file

                increment $line_num
                For each $record in head -$line_num that contains SD| in the first part
                    append the $record in the $file
                    increment $line_num 
            else
                create a $file=$file+1
            fi
        end loop
    end loop
```

Could someone let me know if there is any other effective way to use awk and sed etc to implement this other than the above mentioned high level logic.

Comment: I notice your recent edit -- do you have a reason to believe that my answer *doesn't* already do what you're asking for (re: splitting only at a FORE, keeping it as a set with the following SDs)?

Comment: Hey Charles. sorry about that. I somehow didn't notice it at first so I went ahead and edited my question thinking that I might have not been elaborative, but then immediately noticed that you've taken my point already into account. :). I thank you for that..

Comment: NP. The only place where there's some question of interpretation is whether you want to split at *every* FORE (as @anubhava's answer does), or at the first FORE after a 20mb boundary (as my answer does).

Comment: Oh -- actually, I see you're tagged for ksh. My apologies for having a known bashism in my answer; I'll get that out. (Hopefully it's real David Korn ksh93? That's a lot faster than mksh and the other clones).

Answer (score 1):

Nothing nearly so complex is called for. This can be implemented in pure shell with no external commands at all (no `head`, `awk`, etc).

```
#!/usr/bin/env ksh

max_size=$(( 20 * 1024 * 1024 ))

# Read our three fixed header lines
headers=''
read -r line; headers+="$line"$'\n'
read -r line; headers+="$line"$'\n'
read -r line; headers+="$line"$'\n'

splitNum=1                                             # variable to track file number
splitFileName=$(printf 'split.%04d' "$splitNum")       # generate first filename
exec >"$splitFileName"                                 # and redirect stdout to that file

printf '%s' "${headers}"                               # print our headers...
cur_size=$(( ${#headers} ))                            # and set cur_size to their length

while IFS= read -r line; do                            # For each line:
  # check for and manage rotation
  if [[ $line = "FORE|"* ]]; then                      # If it's a FORE...
    if (( cur_size > max_size )); then                 # ...and over size: start a new file
      (( ++splitNum ))                                 # increment the split number
      splitFileName=$(printf 'split.%04d' "$splitNum") # generate a new filename
      exec >"$splitFileName"                           # redirect stdout to that file
      printf '%s' "${headers}"                         # print headers to stdout
      cur_size=$(( ${#headers} ))                      # reset size to size of headers
    fi
  fi
  # whether or not we had to do any of that:
  printf '%s\n' "$line"                                # print the line we just read
  cur_size=$(( cur_size + ${#line} + 1 ))              # and increment cur_size
done
```

Note that if you were porting this to bash, you might want to change `splitFileName=$(printf 'split.%04d' "$splitNum")` to `printf -v splitFileName 'split.%04d' "$splitNum"`. ksh93 is smart enough to optimize away the subshell involved in the command substitution automatically; bash requires explicit syntax to avoid the overhead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this `awk` command:

```
awk -F '|' 'NR<=3{
   hdr = hdr $0 RS
}
$1=="FORE"{
   close(fn)
   fn="split-" ++n
   printf "%s%s", hdr, $0 RS > fn
}
$1=="SD"{
   print > fn
}
END{close(fn)}' file
```

In one line:

```
awk -F '|' 'NR<=3{hdr = hdr $0 RS} $1=="FORE"{close(fn); fn="split-" ++n; printf "%s%s", hdr, $0 RS > fn} $1=="SD"{print > fn} END{close(fn)}' file
```

Comment: You're doing one file per FORE? I read the question as wanting one file per 20mb, splitting on FORE boundaries. (Note "split on file size" in the spec, and the 20mb value given in pseudocode).

Comment: (awk *is* a good tool for the job; I'm almost tempted to update and test my answer for ksh93 compatibility just to have a hope of staying moderately competitive on performance).

Answer (score 0):

The question would be easier with lines like

```
FORE|20140508|20140214|\rSD|0|0039 - data|data|data|data|\rSD|0|0211 - data|data|data|data|\rSD|0|0039 - data|data|data|data|\rSD|0|0211 - data|data|data|data|
FORE|20140508|20140214|\rSD|0|0039 - data|data|data|data|\rSD|0|0039 - data|data|data|data|\rSD|0|0211 - data|data|data|data|
```

First preprocess the file with `awk`, saving the headers in a temp file and joining lines that start with `SD`.
Now call `split -C 20m filename` with additional parameters you like.
Next `tr "\r" "\n"` into different lines and add the headers in all files.

EDIT: Preprocessing for joined lines can be done with

```
awk 'NR<=3 { print >> "filename.head" }
   /^FORE/ { printf("%s%s",skipFirstNewline, $0); skipFirstNewline="\n" }
   /^SD/ { printf("\r%s",$0) }
   END{printf "\n" }' filename
```

When you are checking the results, you will get confused by the carriage returns `\r`. So replace `\r` temporary with `rr` when you want to check the output.

Comment: Very Good Idea. But just struggling on how to implement the pre-processing  part of joining the lines using awk. Still figuring out